# Getting error while using address.transfer solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am getting an error while using address.transfer function in solidity contract and transaction getting reverted

"Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert at PromiEvent"

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract MyContract {
function payEther(address payable _wallet, uint _amount) public {
     _wallet.transfer(_amount);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue , contract address must be payable address, also should have enough balance. A [Fallback](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/contracts.html#fallback-function) function with external visibility makes contract address payable

Answer (score 0):

Be careful [using transfer function](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/). It is [better to use call function](https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/) with [reentrancy guard](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.0/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol).